# Unable to inspect element on HTML page (right click inspect element)

Tags: java, html, css, google-chrome-devtools

For example, go to [Yahoo](https://www.yahoo.com/), and try to right click -> inspect element on the arrow button eluded to in the picture below.

[image]

Nothing will popup so I'm unable to inspect element, and when inspecting the DOM I cannot seem to locate this element their either.

Any guidance one how to add this functionality back in would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**  Here is a screenshot of what the DOM looks like when I try to select the element. [image]

The div below the one I have highlighted only selects the pictures and captions between the arrow buttons.

Comment: Are you able to open the dev tools and click on the inspect button inside it?

Comment: check this link https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Yes, I can open devtools and I can inspect every other element on the page.  For some reason, those arrow buttons within the div element with id="yui_3_8_1_1_1431061654371_796" are not showing up anywhere for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did got to Yahoo.com, and tried inspecting the element that you have shown. I was able to inspect it normally. [ Im using Chrome, on Mac - Yosemite ].

Here is the code that I found. May be you can use that.

```
<button type="button" class="FilmstripBtn NextBtn ButtonNaked Wpx-20 Pos-a End-0 T-0 B-0 Fz-30 Z-1 " data-jump-to="next" title="Next" data-action-outcome="pgnt" data-ylk="t1:a3;t2:td;t3:nav;sec:td-fea;elm:btn;elmt:ne;itc:1;" data-rapid_p="6" id="yui_3_12_0_1_1431061078340_1326"><i class="Icon W-a" id="yui_3_12_0_1_1431061078340_1329"></i></button>
```

Comment: Very strange. I'm on Yosemite with Chrome Version 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit), and it will not let me inspect that element.  I've been using devtools in Chrome for months and have never encountered this issue before.

Comment: Are you able to open Dev Tools ? Using View->Developer->Developer Tools ? If so, you can find the button inside the Elements tab in DevTools.

Comment: When I view page source (view-source:https://www.yahoo.com/) I cannot find that button with class "FilmstripBtn" in the source html, and when I view the elements tab in the development panel I cannot locate it.  Like I mentioned, I've used the developer panel many times.  This is the first time in about 5 months that I haven't been able to locate a button on a page in the elements tab.  And for some reason when I right click on the button itself no menu appears.

Answer (score 0):

Made a little progress.  For some reason Chrome still won't let me right click inspect element (maybe a bug), but I was able to find the buttons in the elements tab. They are actually "a" tags and not buttons on my end.

I had difficulty before because they are labeled differently for me than what is shown from the other response to this question, and the "a" tags won't become highlighted unless I expand the divs and select the actual "a" tag (possibly another chrome bug?).  [image: than what is posted above. Here is a screenshot of what my]